# При запуске файла с компьютера ,заменяет русский язык на символы LaTex

Tags: latex

Есть готовый код, который раньше спокойно запускался и работал,но при запуске на другом компьютере (причем и в LaTex и онлайн через overleaf) заменяет русский язык на символы. Подскажите в чем проблема.

Кусок кода для примера:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \large
    \textbf{ÌÈÍÈÑÒÅÐÑÒÂÎ ÎÁÐÀÇÎÂÀÍÈß È ÍÀÓÊÈ ÐÔ}

   \textbf{Ôåäåðàëüíîå ãîñóäàðñòâåííîå áþäæåòíîå îáðàçîâàòåëüíîå\\ó÷ðåæäåíèå âûñøåãî ïðîôåññèîíàëüíîãî îáðàçîâàíèÿ}

    \textbf{ÏÅÍÇÅÍÑÊÈÉ ÃÎÑÓÄÀÐÑÒÂÅÍÍÛÉ ÓÍÈÂÅÐÑÈÒÅÒ}
    \vspace{1cm}

    \textbf{Ôàêóëüòåò âû÷èñëèòåëüíîé òåõíèêè}

    Êàôåäðà <<Âûñøåé è ïðèêëàäíîé ìàòåìàòèêè>>
    \vfill

    \textbf{Êóðñîâàÿ ðàáîòà}\\
    ïî äèñöèïëèíå <<Ìàòåìàòè÷åñêîå ìîäåëèðîâàíèå>>\\
    òåìà:<<Ìîäåëè, ïîëó÷àåìûå íà îñíîâå ñîõðàíåíèÿ ýíåðãèè>>
\end{center}
\vfill
```

Comment: Кодировку проверяли? Может другая стоит

Comment: Вы специально скрыли преамбулу, чтобы была работа для предсказательницы?  И не говорите в какой системе запускался (версия дистрибутива латеха), каким редактором добились столь выдающихся успехов... Ванга говорит, что у Вас проблема с кодировками. Как минимум - с входной кодировкой текста. Судя по символам, Вы изначально использовали досовскую (cp866) кодировку, потом зачем-то этот файл открыли в виндовской кодировке (cp1251). Что касается Overleaf - они вообще хотят кодировку UTF-8.